# Loan Calculator in ASP.NET from a Console Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I just finished working on a console application in witch I created a loan calculator.  My code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LoanCalculator
{
    public class LoanCalculator
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // declare variables
            double principle = 0; 
            double years = 0;
            double interest = 0;
            string principleInput, yearsInput, interestInput;


            // User input for Principle amount in dollars
            Console.Write("Enter the loan amount, in dollars(0000.00): ");
            principleInput = Console.ReadLine();
            principle = double.Parse(principleInput);
            //Prompt the user to reenter any illegal input
            if (principle < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The value for the mortgage cannot be a negative value");
                principle = 0;
            }


            // User input for number of years
            Console.Write("Enter the number of years: ");
            yearsInput = Console.ReadLine();
            years = double.Parse(yearsInput);
            //Prompt the user to reenter any illegal input
            if (years < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Years cannot be a negative value");
                years = 0;
            }

            // User input for interest rate
            Console.Write("Enter the interest rate(%): ");
            interestInput = Console.ReadLine();
            interest = double.Parse(interestInput);
            //Prompt the user to reenter any illegal input
            if (interest < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The value for the interest rate cannot be a negative value");
                interest = 0;
            }

            //Calculate the monthly payment
            //ADD IN THE .Net function call Math.pow(x, y) to compute xy (x raised to the y power). 
            double loanM = (interest / 1200.0);
            double numberMonths = years * 12;
            double negNumberMonths = 0 - numberMonths;
            double monthlyPayment = principle * loanM / (1 - System.Math.Pow((1 + loanM), negNumberMonths));

            //double totalPayment = monthlyPayment;


            //Output the result of the monthly payment
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("The amount of the monthly payment is: {0}{1:0.00}", "$", monthlyPayment));
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to end. . .");
            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

Everything above works out as planned.  I am now trying to convert this into an ASP.NET web application using Visual Studio and I am stuck. My current UI I have set up with 3 labels for principle input (with a text box), loan duration (with radio button list) , and interest rate (with dropdownList).

My problem I am having is I am trying to get a radiobutton list in for my loan duration (15, 30, or other) as my selections. If the user selects Other, I am trying to implement a textbox for them to type in a value in years.  After the user selects his intended duration I want my InterestRate to be a drop down list item with 1%-10% as options.

I also have a button called "Calculate" where it calculates the solution from the users input. If someone could lead me into the right direction on how to approach this. I am brand new to working with ASP.NET and I am confused how to successfully transform my console application to an ASP.NET project.  Thanks for the help!

My Page looks as follows:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
     <title>Monthly Mortgage Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <h1>Monthly Payment Loan Calculator</h1>
    </div>

     <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Please enter the principle amount">     </asp:Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrinciple" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" 
        Text="Please enter the loan duration in years"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem>15 Years</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>30 Years</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Other</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <br />
  nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&n    bsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtYears" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Please select the interest rate">    </asp:Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Monthly Payment" />

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post up some of your asp markup code, what does the page look like

Comment: @Mikey Mouse Code has been updated

Comment: Looks good. You need to add the OnClick Method to either the Button Markup or in your code Behind with "+="
There's an example in my solution, put a break point on to see if it works

Answer (score 2):

Here are some general steps to convert the project. If you need code, let me know which bit.

1) Create an empty Asp.net Application (Not web page)

2) Add some asp.net tags to the markup (not the code behind)
It'll look like

```
          <asp:TextBox ID="tbYears" runat="server" />
          <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblDuration" runat="server" >
                 <asp:ListItem Text="15" Value="15" />
                  ...
          </asp:RadioButtonList>
          <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

3) put any startup code in your Page_Load Method

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
     }
```

4) Write your button click event

```
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          double years = double.parse(tbYears.text); // This will throw an exception if a user doesn't input a number
          var duration = rblDuration.SelectedValue // Needs to be cast too as it comes back as a string
    }
```

That should get you started

Edit:

Another tip: Change

```
           <asp:ListItem>15 Years</asp:ListItem>
```

into

```
          <asp:ListItem Value="15" Text="15 Years" />
```

Makes it easier to parse the value

Comment: @DaBulls33 Looks good, in markup code, try to name your Controls so someone looking at the code behind can see what's happening. So instead of "DropDownList1" call it "ddlInterestRate" (just a tip)

Comment: @Mickey I'm just confused how to start the button click event, and how to get the monthly payment code working into this application.

Comment: Ok, put the OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" code in your button markup. Put the  "protected void btnSubmit_Click" method as above in the same class as your Page_Load, usually just below it. Put a break point on that method. Fire up the web site, and click the "Submit" button... it should stop at your break point

Comment: Right, I gotta go, hope that helps. If ya need any more help with this, best go check out a Asp.net tutorial

Answer (score 0):

In general, you will be able to use the same logic, except that i would move to it to a class.

1) Where you have console inputs, you will be able to use a textbox.
2) Where you have the result on a WriteLine() you may want to use a Label to display the result.

ASP.NET pages will have a .aspx file which will hold the markup (HTML), and a .cs file which will house the codebehind. Page elements can be given events that will invoke a method in the codebehind.

For instance, select your submit button in the design view then look for the events button in the Properties pane. You should be able to add a new event for the button click. Which will map the click of the button to a method in the codebehind:

```
protected void importBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Textbox1.Text = "Editing the Textbox contents";
}
```

You can access the Properties for the controls as shown.

Good Luck, hope this helps.

Comment: so all I really need to do is create a TextChanged event for the Principle and put the user input code I have for the console appliction in this event?

Comment: You could do that instead of using a submit button event, if you wanted to, yes - then it would just be a case of setting the text property of a label instead of Console.WriteLine().